# Addressing schemes used for expandable RAM's?

Tags: processor, cpu-architecture

Hi people I was wondering about something called addressing schemes that the operating systems use for expandable RAM's. Let us consider an example to throw some light on this.

"If we have a 32 bit architecture for the computer then this means we have a computer address that is 32-bit long which amounts to 2^32 addressable memory location approximately 4GB of data."

But if we add another 4GB of main memory that is now 8GB of RAM in effect, how does the computer address the extra main memory locations because that additional amount exceeds the range of a 32 bit address which is 2^32.

Can anyone throw some light on this question.

Comment: You are looking for [Physical Address Extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension), also known as PAE.  SO is for programming related questions; so your question might be closed as off topic.

Comment: This is not off topic. PAE is part of the instruction set architecture, the interface between the hardware and the programmer. If you program on the bare metal, you have to know this type of stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you can't address 8GB with just 32bits. At any given point in time using 32bits you can only choose from 4G memory locations  .

A popular workaround is to use physical addresses which are larger than 32 bits in the [page tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_table). This allows the operating system to define which subset of the 8GB a program is able to access. However, this subset can never be bigger than 4GB. [x86 PAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension) is one example, but there are [others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerPC_e500) which do just the same.

With this workaround the operating system itself can access the whole 8GB only by changing it's own page table. E.g. to access a memory location, it first has to map the memory location into its own address space by changing the page table, and only then can start accessing the memory location. Of course this is very cumbersome (to say the least). It can also lead to problems if parts of the operating system were written without considering this type of memory extension, device drivers are a typical example.

The problem is not new. 8bit Computers like Commodores C64 used [bank switching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bank_switching) to access more than 64KB with 16bit addresses. Early PCs used [expanded memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expanded_Memory_System) to work around the 640KB limit. The Right Thing (TM) is of course to switch to bigger addresses before you have to resort to ugly solutions.